# What is the proper notation for cartesian coordinates with decimals in your native language?

Tags: notation, article-writing, mathematical-french

For simple integers, `(1, 2)` is what most people are taught in elementary school. This appears to be true regardless or whether their language's decimal separator is a period (.) or a comma (,).

But what happens if we are dealing with decimal coordinates? What is the proper notation in your native language? I have struggled to find authoritative sources on the subject for French, in particular. I found [this](https://geoconfluences.ens-lyon.fr/glossaire/coordonnees/@@download_pdf?id=coordonnees&uid=8d55109189ba478b88dd3ae2d89138e1), but geographical coordinates are a separate question.

Here are the options I found:

1. `(5,4, 3,2)`  5. `(5.4, 3.2)`
2. `(5,4 3,2)`   6. `(5.4 3.2)`
3. `(5,4; 3,2)`  7. `(5.4; 3.2)`
4. `(5,4;3,2)`   8. `(5.4;3.2)`

Comment: I doubt there could be one single world-wide valid notation, since [decimal separators and digit grouping](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9parateur_d%C3%A9cimal_et_s%C3%A9parateur_de_milliers) varies, even within a country (Switzerland). For practical reasons I'd suggest to use the locale settings of your computer.

Comment: Please read the question before answering. This is not about unified standards or decimal separators; I'm expressly interested in knowing what notation is customary in *your* native language/area when it comes to coordinates with decimals. Do you know of any software that would feature such coordinates with correct localization?

Comment: Pls consider my reply before complaining. Malfeasant as I am I linked intentionally to French Wikipedia, what is incomplete in regard to your query -- but a nice crystal nucleus for _your own investigations_, which could lead to [a map](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dezimaltrennzeichen#/media/Datei:DecimalSeparator.svg). A corresponding software? Yes: Microsoft Windows 7 or 10, maybe 11 too. Besides the decimal separator and digit grouping it also defines the data delimiter. HTH

Comment: The question is the same as how to separate function arguments, so not even limited to Cartesian coordinates. Also: I do not see a jurisdiction in any country of the world that could stop software programmers from using any convention they like as long as it works. Same applies to article writers (your tag).